# About transfer file in hdfs

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I need to transfer files from one hdfs folder to another hdfs folder in java code.

May I ask is there api that we can call to transfer files among hdfs paths?

Also I'd like to ask is there anyway to invoke a mapreduce job from java code? Of course, this java not running in hdfs.

Thank you very much and have a great weekend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> May I ask is there api that we can call to transfer files among hdfs paths?

Use the [o.a.h.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DistributedFileSystem.html)#rename method to move file from one folder in HDFS to another folder. The function has been overloaded and one of the method takes [Options.Rename](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Options.Rename.html) as a parameter.

FYI .... I haven't checked the code, but I think that rename involves changes to the name space and not any actual block movements.

> Also I'd like to ask is there anyway to invoke a mapreduce job from java code? Of course, this java not running in hdfs.

Hadoop is written in Java, so there should be a way :) Use the [o.a.h.mapreduce.Job#submit](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#submit%28%29) and [o.a.h.mapreduce.Job#waitForCompletion](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#waitForCompletion%28boolean%29) methods.